# Showing multiple markers in google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

i have a set of lat long coordinates. i want to display all of those markers at a time on google map. I know how to display a single marker. But don't know how to display multiples at once. Anybody please help me.

Thank you.

i have lat long points.

like

> id = 123 lat = 12.00 lon = 77.00
>
> id = 124 lat = 12.01 lon = 77.01

etc.

Comment: Check This http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-multiple-marker-locations-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-and-save-it-in-shared-preferences/

Comment: i went through that blog. already. it is to ADD markers on map. I want to display markers for my lat long points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**May This Help You**

```
       for(int pin=0; pin<pins.size(); pin++)
       {
             LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(pins.get(pin).latitude), Float.parseFloat(pins.get(pin).longitude));
             Marker storeMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(pinLocation)
              .title(pins.get(pin).pinname)
              .snippet(pins.get(pin).address)
           );
       }
```

Comment: Possible to duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827124/adding-multiple-markers-on-google-map-v2

Comment: Reference From : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972476/how-to-show-multiple-marker-on-google-map-android

Answer (score 0):

Create a `LatLng` object by using following format:

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

Then call the method with your `LatLng` object along with your `GoogleMap` object:

```
    private Marker setCurrentLocation(LatLng location, GoogleMap map) {
        BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.user_location_pin);

        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location)
                .icon(bitmapDescriptor).title(location.toString()));

        return marker;
    }
```

Comment: in location can i store multiple lat long position..?? How.?

Comment: You can create LatLng objects and pass them to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LatLng one = new LatLng(2.40744, 77.014702);//Latitude and long points
    LatLng two = new LatLng(2.407440, 77.014702);
              .......
        Similarly u can use more lat and long 

     myMarkerOne = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(one)//use LatLng obj
    .title("C") 
    .snippet("dsfd")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

    myMarkerTwo = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(two)
    .title("C") 
    .snippet("dsfds")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

refer this: [How to add multiple marker and overlay in v2 google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184002/how-to-add-multiple-marker-and-overlay-in-v2-google-map)

Also check this [link:](http://androidmapv2.blogspot.in/2013/11/adding-multiple-marker-locations-in.html)

Comment: Yes you are right.. but he working with two markers, then I think it's not a problem. If he went for more than two then he must went for loop.